# Prove: set of the polynomials of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Q $ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $P_n =\{p(x)=a_n x^n+ a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+ a_1 x+a_0 |a_i \in \Bbb Q \}$ the set of the polynomials of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Q $

Prove that $P_n$ is countable and tell why $P= \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty P_n$ the set of all the polynomials with coefficient in $\Bbb Q $ is countable.

How  can I prove that $|P_n|=|Q|^{n+1}$ ?

Comment: countable union of countable sets is countable

Comment: What theorems do you have? Do you know that the cartesian product of countable sets is countable? That there is a bijections $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$? This is probably where you should start.

Comment: Define a function $f: \mathbb{Q}^{n+1 }\to P_n$ given by $f(a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)=a_0 +a_1 x+ a_2 x^2 +\cdots+a_nx^n$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$. This is bijective function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\Bbb Q$ is countable and each coefficient (of which there are $n+1$) is from $\Bbb Q$. Now use the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

It might help to note that each polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$ is equivalent to a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$ (why?). If you can find an injection from $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$, you can try to extend the idea to $\Bbb Z\times\cdots\times\Bbb Z$, $(n+1)$-copies of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

For $p_n(x)$, a n degree polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, there are only n+1 coefficients ($a_i$'s). If these n+1 coefficients are fixed, the polynomial is fixed.

Now, total number of such $p_n (x)$ i.e. $|P_n|$ is $|\mathbb{Q}|^{n+1}$   (each coefficient could take any value in $\mathbb{Q}$), which is countable.

Hence, $|P_n|$ is countable.

We know that countable union of countable sets is countable $\implies |P|$ is countable

Comment: That's what I thought, but How can I prove that $|P_n|=|Q|^{n+1} $?

Comment: Actually, we cannot say this. But with this kind of approach we can show that $|P_n|$ is countable. Use combinatorics. Similar example: How many 4 digits number are there? In a 4 digit number, we have 4 places to fill which can be filled by only ${0,1, \dots ,9}$. So, number of 4 digits number are 9*10*10*10 (since first place cannot be zero). Similarly, here you have n+1 places (coefficients) and $|\mathbb{Q}|$ ways to fill them

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** you may use the [Cantor-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) to prove that:
$$\left| P_n \right| = \left|\mathbb{Q}^n\right| = \left|\mathbb{N}^n\right| = \left|\mathbb{N}\right| = \aleph_0. $$

Comment: From this we can easily show  that the set all algebraic numbers is countable  but since the reals are uncountable, we deduce the existence of transcendental numbers  without explicitly displaying one.

Comment: It seems to me that it's fairly straightforward to directly prove each of these sets has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers (i.e. without invoking the "big hammer" Cantor-Bernstein theorem).