# Fundamental theorem of Algebra to prove countable set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Ok so I have this as the prompt. 
Fixing $n \in \Bbb{N}$ let $A_{n}$ be the set of algebraic numbers obtained as roots of polynomials with integer coefficients that have degree $n$. Using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra we know that every polynomial has a finite number of roots, show that $A_{n}$ is countable.

Hint: For each $m \in \Bbb{N}$, consider polynomials $a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \cdots +a_{1}x+a_{0}$ that satisfy $|{a_n}| + |{a_{n-1}}| + \cdots + |{a_1}| + |{a_0}| \leq m$

I am lost as to where to start, and the hint I guess is lost on me.

Could we use the fact that since $|{a_n}| + |{a_{n-1}}| + \cdots + |{a_1}| + |{a_0}| \leq m$ all are in $\Bbb{R}$ we can say for each $m\in \Bbb{N} $  ,$-m \leq {a_n} + {a_{n-1}} + \cdots + {a_1} + {a_0} \leq m$

I suspect that using the fundamental theorem of algebra and finite roots is a clue towards establishing that this implies $An$ is denumerable and from that countable but not clear on proper. Sorry if this is all over the place I have been spinning my wheels for days on this.

Comment: The coefficients are integers so for each $m$ there are only a finite number of coefficients whose absolute values sum to a number less than or equal to $m$. Is the sum of a countable number of finite numbers countable?

Comment: Aren't $a_1$, $a_2$, ... elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, not of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354323/algebraic-numbers-as-roots-of-polynomials-of-degree-n-are-countable also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420096/prove-set-of-the-polynomials-of-degree-n-with-coefficients-in-bbb-q-is-co and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441140/proof-that-the-set-of-algebraic-numbers-is-countable and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2366117/prove-that-the-set-of-all-algebraic-numbers-is-countable-proof-using-fundamenta and many more.

Comment: *Using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra* --- You don't need to use anything nearly this strong or this difficult to prove. It is sufficient to know that a polynomial with degree $n$ has AT MOST $n$ many roots, which is typically proved in college algebra and precalculus texts when the remainder theorem is discussed. FYI, this is the theorem that says if $r$ is a root of the polynomial $P(x),$ then $x-r$ is a factor of $P(x).$